# The keyword this is not giving me the current object, only its parent. How do I get at the current object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a variable that refers to the current object/function.

I mistakenly thought `this` would do it:

```
var fn1=function(){
    var _this=this;
    _this.prop='hey!';
    console.log(_this);
};
```

The console log output the browser window object, which I found confusing until I read `this`:

[`this` keyword Function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context)

Can anyone explain to me why, in javascript, `this` refers to the parent?

As a result of all of `this` Ive been thinking about using something like `this`:

```
var fn2=function(){
    var _this=(function(){
        return this;
    })();
    _this.prop='hey!';
    console.log(_this);
};
```

But is there a better way or simply a correct way I am missing, to get at the current object from inside itself?

Comment: There are dozens of questions on the meaning of 'this' around here.  You may want to give some of these a go: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+what+does+this+refer+to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me why, in javascript, `this` refers to the parent?

The value of `this` depends on how you call the function.

If you call the function in the context of an object (`foo.method()`) then `this` is `foo` because it is useful to have access to the object to which the method belongs when performing OOP.

> But is there a better way or simply a correct way I am missing, to get at the current object from inside itself?

What current object?

If you want to use a constructor function, then use [the `new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```
function Dog(name, breed) {
    this._name = name;
    this._breed = breed;
}

var myDog = new Dog("Fifi", "Poodle");
alert(myDog._name);
```